# Django filtering last JSONField object

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

estoy intentando hacer un filter de un JSONField que tiene la siguiente data:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T11:39:07.447677",
    "staff": "payment_in_process"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T11:39:12.700590",
    "state": "ASSIGNING",
    "staff": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T11:40:38.974475",
    "state": "ASSIGNED",
    "staff": "Marco"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T12:05:54.834831",
    "state": "BUYING",
    "staff": "Marco Alejandro"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T13:30:13.426935",
    "state": "DELIVERING",
    "staff": "Marco Alejandro"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T14:11:44.572710",
    "state": "DELIVERED",
    "staff": "Marco Alejandro"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T14:11:45.895028",
    "state": "DELIVERED",
    "staff": "Marco Alejandro"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-02T14:11:46.781141",
    "state": "DELIVERED",
    "staff": "Marco Alejandro"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-04T18:01:22.575038",
    "state": "DELIVERED_RATED",
    "staff": "Marco Alejandro"
  }
]
```

Este JSON es un JSONField que almacena todos los estados de una orden junto con la fecha en la que ese estado cambio y va agregando mas elementos conforme la orden cambia de estados. Lo que estoy intentado hacer es obtener un reporte comparando la fecha del ultimo objecto del JSONField con una fecha data.

Hacerlo con el primer elemento del del JSONField es muy facil lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
date1 = request.data.get("date1", None)
date1_parsed = datetime.strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

orders = Order.objects.filter(history__0__date__range=(date1_parsed, date2_parsed))
```

lo que no puedo hacer es como apuntar siempre al ultimo elemento, no puedo quemar un valor puesto que cada orden tendrá un tamaño diferente del JSONField.

Comment: Hola, ¿a qué te refieres con quemar un valor?

Comment: osea que no puedo ponerle __0__ como en el ejemplo por que siempre buscara en el objeto de la pocicion 0, lo que deseo es que busque siempre en el ultimo objecto del JSONField. El problema es que no todos los registros de la base vana tener el mismo tamaño de JSONField

Comment: Un Json o un diccionario no tienen "orden", si el "orden" es importante usa una lista, si no, usa un diccionario con keys y valores que te será mas fácil recuperar la información.

Yo creo que lo que estás haciendo no se debería hacer por un json, pero si lo explicas más tal vez te podamos sugerir una solución